# Does refelection return names of properties sorted alphabetically?

Tags: c#

```
List<PropertyInfo> propInfo = typeof(MM_WIRES_OFFICE_ACC_CUTOFF).GetProperties().ToList();
DbParams[] parm = new DbParams[propInfo.Count];
int count = 0;

foreach (var info in propInfo)
{
    parm[count] = new DbParams(info.Name, DbType.String, entity.ACCOUNT);

    count++;
}
```

Can I do that? How will I make sure info.Name is same properties entity...
Does reflection give me attributes sorted alphabetically ?

Comment: What does MSDN say... Why call ToList when you're going to iterate over it once... And it's already an array... You'd know this if you read MSDN... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

Comment: Thanks!! How should I do exact map attributes with entity class??

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can sort it: GetProperties().OrderBy(p=>p.Name)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

Use `OrderBy` to get the ordering you need.